# Ayuda! Inserción de registros en PostgreSQL con SP desde Codeigniter

Tags: array, postgresql, stored-procedure, codeigniter-3

comunidad en esta Oportunidad vengo por acá con un pequeño asunto y es que no logro realizar una inserción de Gran cantidad de registros desde Codeigniter a la BD PostgreSQL, la cuestion es que no se como llamar este tipo de Procedimientos de Almacenado desde Codeigniter.
El asunto en detalle esta en que necesito insertar una fila de muchos datos en la BD con un procedimiento almacenado, pero necesito hacer la llamada de la Funcion de PostgeSQL desde Codeigniter(PHP) y la verdad no encuentro la manera de como hacerlo. Aca les dejo un Codigo de Ejemplo a ver si me pueden Ayudar;

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
<fielset>
    <legend>Prueba</legend>
    <form name="Ftest" action="Grupouno/prueba" method="POST">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Nombre</label>            
            <input type="text" name="nom" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Email</label>            
            <input type="text" name="mail" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Telefono</label>            
            <input type="text" name="tlf" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <br>  
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>        
    </form>
</fielset>
```

**Función en el Controlador**

```
public function prueba() {

    $data = [
        $_POST['nom'],
        $_POST['mail'],
        $_POST['tlf']
    ];

    //print_r($data);die();

    if($data != null) {
        $this->categoria_model->fn_prueba($_POST);
        print 'ok';
    }else{
        print ':(';
    }
}
```

**Función en el Modelo**

```
public function fn_prueba($data) { 

    /* (01) $query = $this->db->query("SELECT unnest({('nombre','myEmail@email.com','04150001254')}::info[]);"); */
    /* (02) $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM unnest('{(".$data.")}'::info[]);"); */
    /* (03) */ $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM insert_info('{$data}'::info[]);");
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Aca en el Modelo, probe de estas 03 maneras pero me sigue dando Error;

- la primera manera **(01)** fue pasando los datos Directamente y dio error.
- la segunda manera **(02)** fue pasando el arreglo de datos y tambien resulto error.
- la tercera manera **(03)** pasando los datos directamente a la Fn y tambien arrojo Error.

**Funcion en PostgreSQL**

```
CREATE TYPE info AS(
name  varchar,
email_add  varchar,
contact_no  varchar
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_info(
info_array  info[]
) RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE
    info_element  info;
BEGIN
    FOREACH info_element IN ARRAY info_array
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO info_table(
            name,
            email_add,
            contact_no
        ) VALUES(
            info_element.name,
            info_element.email_add,
            info_element.contact_no
        );
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 'OK';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**NOTA:** si Ejecuto las querys:

`SELECT * FROM unnest('{"(nombre1,myEmail@email.com,04150001245)"
                     , "(nombre2,my2Email@email.com,04150001246)"
                     ,"(nombre3,my3Email@email.com,04150001247)"}'::info[]);`

**o**

```
SELECT insert_info('{"(nombre,myEmail@email.com,04150001254)"}'::info[]);
```

directamente en la BD Funciona a la Perfeccion, pero no logro hacer esa misma llamada desde PHP con Codeigniter, lo cual es lo que necesito.

**Resultados de Querys.**

*Query (01)*

```
Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{" LINE 1: SELECT unnest({('nombre','myEmail@email.com','0415000456')}:... ^
```

*Query (02)*

```
Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: malformed record literal: "(Array)" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM unnest('{(Array)}'::info[]); ^ DETAIL: Too few columns.
```

*Query (03)*

```
Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: malformed array literal: "Array" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM insert_info('Array'::info[]); ^ DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

- De antemano les agradezco por tomarse el tiempo de leer este Post y Ayudar a un necesitado...

Answer (score 1):

Saludos te dejo un ejemplo.

Tengo el siguiente **SP**:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE insertuser(IN nombre VARCHAR(255), IN correo VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO USER(nombre,correo) VALUES(nombre,correo);
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

el uso en **Codeigniter**:

```
CALL insertuser('Mi nombre', 'correo@ejemplo.com');
```

tu código puede ser algo así:

```
$this->db->reconnect();
$sql = "CALL `insertuser`(?, ?)";
$result = $this->db->query($sql,$data);
$this->db->close();
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Gracias @Diego Avila, aun sigo intentando pero nada...:(

Comment: @oarodriguez te sugiero que revieses esto: https://laddu143.wordpress.com/2017/05/17/stored-procedure-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Buenas Tardes! Aun sigo intentando pero no he logrado resultado alguno, y necesito insertar un arreglo de parametros porque son muchos, ojala fueran uno pocos parametros xq con tu ejemplo seria efectivo...

Comment: otro detalle es que los procedimientos almacenados los estoy trabajando desde pgsql, por lo tanto son un poco diferentes que en mysql, es decir, en pgsql se usan funciones y el mysql se utilizan SP, y Las llamadas desde Codeigniter cambian un poco...